# Unable to retrieve the tenant id POSTMAN

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-integration, postman

I am trying to get the tenant id from POSTMAN by following [Access Sharepoint using POSTMAN](https://www.ktskumar.com/2017/01/access-sharepoint-online-using-postman/) i followed the same steps and able to create the App but i unable to get the tenant id the response what i am getting is:

-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException
    Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want retrieve your Tenant with Postman only?

If not, you can find it via:

1. the portal.azure.com > Azure Active Directory > Properties
2. any SharePoint modern page, open Dev Console and search 'siteSubscriptionId'
3. Teams, when you "Get a link to team" you have "&tenantId=..."

Comment: do you mind please help how to get the site path

Comment: Maybe that can help you?: https://blog.lsonline.fr/2019/09/02/how-to-get-your-microsoft-365-tenant-id/